# Какие данные допустимы в теле POST запроса с content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, frontend, request, backend, content-type

Народ, пришел на проект, работал какое-то время с одним человеком по бэку, мы создали что-то вроде мидлвары с конфигом для axios, где указали единые заголовки для get, post запросов с content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, это чем-то было обосновано. В теле post запросов передавали обычный JSON объект. Для каких целей было сделано именно так, не помню.

Сейчас на бэк пришел новый человек и утверждает, что это категорически не правильно и из-за этого не может использовать часть либ, хотя до этого никаких проблем не возникало. Сменить конфиг или передавать туда контент тайп не принципиально, но хочется разобраться, почему так нельзя или почему так можно???

СОБСТВЕННО ВОПРОС:
в чем реальная причина того, что нельзя передавать данные по типу {"data": ..., "anything": ["ddd", ...]} с content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded??? или это допустимо???

Comment: Потому что json и x-www-form-urlencoded — это, очевидно, абсолютно разные форматы

Comment: При `x-www-form-urlencoded` надо передавать данные в виде `variable=val&variable2=val`, для json данных надо `application/json`. Правильно понимаю что прежде чем передать json вы его приводили к строке выше указанного вида?

Comment: Вообще нет, на бэке была такая строка:
data = request.get_json, которая получала в json формате с данным контент-тайпом.
Ну и просьба была, делать именно с ним, чем-то было обосновано. Я понял, как вывод, вариант без приведения к виду variable=val&variable2=val не правильный при использовании типа x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Я так понимаю Вы вручную написали функцию(`request.get_json`) которая принимала Вами отправленный не правильный формат данных и парсила его чтобы вытащить данные, такая строка скорее всего приходила на сервер с ткаим видом: `{'тут переданный json в виде строки': null}`. То есть Вы написали парсер не правильно отправленных данных. Если бы Вы отправляли через json, то на сервере уже была json строка которую можно легко обработать или даже уже обработанная за Вас json строка преобразованная в js.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Разобрался, я с бэком не работаю, но все в действительности так, как описали.